# Closeness weighted sDNA Analysis

Tags: network, sdna

I am doing sDNA processing.

I'm trying a set closeness/farness centrality processes, differing the origin weights. But the results are not showing numerical differences for the MAD/MED, NQPD and other accessibility indexes.

The analysis seems not to consider the weights.

Would you have a tip for these analyses?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly what you would expect from changing origin weights alone, as MAD/MED and NQPD all quantify *destination* weights within a radius of each origin.

Origin weights should affect Betweenness and Two Phase Destination (TPD) measures - does changing origin weights change these?

What happens if you change destination weights - does that change these results?

If the answer to both of the above is no, analysis which is insensitive to changing parameters can hint at problems with the input data. In this case I would check both that you are using your projection of choice (which affects how the radius is measured) and that link connectivities (LConn) look sensible.